# I am unable to understand the error in this code that is preventing an output to be displayed

Tags: verilog

```
module Calculator(out,a,b,op);
  input [3:0] a,b;
  input [1:0] op;
  output [4:0] out;

  reg [32:0] out;
  
  initial
  begin
    case(op)
      2'b00: out <= a+b;
      2'b01: out <= a-b;
      2'b10: out <= a*b;
      2'b11: out <= a/b;
    endcase
    out = a+b;
  end
endmodule

module test_Calci;
      reg [3:0]a,b;
      reg [1:0] op;
      wire [32:0] out;
      
Calculator ca1 (out,a,b,op);

initial
begin
    #40 a=32'b1; b=32'b1; op = 2'b00;
end
endmodule
```

The code is successfully compiling, but the expected output is not being displayed.

[image: The attached image is of the simulation.]

Answer (score 0):

The `initial` block inside the `Calculator` module only executes once at time 0.  At that time, the last statement which is executed (`out = a+b`) assigns `out` to the value X because `a` and `b` are X.  `out` never gets assigned again.

You want `out` to be assigned every time any of the inputs change value.  To do that, use an `always` block:

```
module Calculator(out,a,b,op);
  input [3:0] a,b;
  input [1:0] op;
  output reg [32:0] out;
  
  always @* begin
    case(op)
      2'b00: out = a+b;
      2'b01: out = a-b;
      2'b10: out = a*b;
      2'b11: out = a/b;
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

I made other changes to your code as well.  For combinational logic, it is a good practice to use blocking assignments (`=`) instead of nonblocking (`<=`).

You should not have the assignment to `out` outside of the `case` statement since it will override the value assigned in the `case`.

You declare `out` with 2 different bit widths (5 and 33), which is a little strange.  I merged them into one declaration.